# How to highlight interactable objects in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've missed numerous chests because I didn't see them when going through dungeon - is there a way to highlight interactable objects? Or am I destined to crawl through every corner of every room in order to find all chests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no highlighting of interactive objects in Skyrim. It would defeat the purpose of most puzzles, although it can get frustrating at times. Just be on the lookout and use the local map to help determine if you've seen everything.

Answer (score 2):

This is intentional: They made chests blend in and hid them in hard-to-find places to create a more engaging loot-seeking experience.

As for your answer, a modder will probably do this. If not, I will :p